# Split a 2D numpy array where uneven splits are possible

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an 2D numpy arrays in python which correspond to image that are calculated in a for-loop. The size of the arrays are Nx40. I want in each step of the loop to split the initial that arrays into rectangular arrays of size 40x40 (approximately). In case that N cannot divided with 40 then the last image should contain the remaining of the division. Therefore, for example of 87x40 should be (40x40 and 47x40). What I did so far:

```
div_num = spec.shape[0] / spec.shape[1]
remaining = spec.shape[0] % spec.shape[1]

lista = []
for i in range(1, div_num+1):
     img = spec[((i-1)*40):(i*40)][0:40]
     lista.append(img)
```

How can I add the remaining rows in the last image?

Comment: In your for loop, you could check the number of remaining "rows" and then define `img` accordingly using an if statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `np.array_split` which deals with uneven splits quite superbly. First, I'll initialise some random array:

```
arr = np.random.randn(87, 40)
```

Next, compute the indices to split on. If the shape of `arr` is divisible by 40, then generate even splits. Otherwise, overflows go into the (n - 1)th array.

```
# compute the indices to split on
if arr.shape[0] % 40 == 0:
    split_idx = arr.shape[0] // 40
else:
    split_idx = np.arange(40, arr.shape[0], 40)[:-1]
```

Finally, call `array_split`, and split on `split_idx`:

```
# split along the 0th axis
splits = np.array_split(arr, split_idx, axis=0)
```

Verify that our array was partitioned correctly:

```
[s.shape for s in splits]
[(40, 40), (47, 40)]
```

Comment: In my case the image is 81x40 and the result is 3 matrices two of size 40x40 and one 1x40. How can I avoid that? Also if you try your code with 81,40 you will see the same issue.

Comment: One last question, how could I possible have a threshold of 20 rows and do the following in the case i have 53x40 to keep one image while when it is 63x40 to split it in two?

Comment: @konstantin That's a little difficult, but you could possibly modify the code that generates `split_idx` and get it done.

Comment: ok thanks again! I guess i will need to play a little bit with the else statement.